# JavaScript Loop pushing only the last object every time

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, closures

I am new to JavaScript, I am stuck in the below code, where I am trying to store the *row* by calling the function which creates a JSON object and returns the object, I am pushing the same object to the *data[]* variable, but every time it stores only the last row in data[].

```
function getData(num,callback) {
    for(i = 0;i<headers.length;i++){
        var nextCell = sheet[
            XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r: num, c: i})
        ];
        if( typeof nextCell === 'undefined' ){
            row[headers[i]] = '';
            } else row[headers[i]] = nextCell.w;
    }
    callback(row);
}
for(let rowNum = 4; rowNum <= 15; rowNum++){
    getData(rowNum,function(row){
    data.push(row)
    })
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining data[] ?

Comment: You forgot to declare `row` and initialise it as a new object in every call.

Comment: Your [`i` variable is accidentally global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I have declared `var row = {};` before starting by inner loop and it worked !!!

Comment: **Updated Code** `for(rowNum = 4; rowNum <= range.e.r; rowNum++){                           var row = {};   for(i = 0;i<headers.length;i++){ var nextCell = sheet[                            XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r: rowNum, c: i})]; 
 if( typeof nextCell === 'undefined' ){
   row[headers[i]] = '';
   } else row[headers[i]] = nextCell.w;
}
data.push(row);  }`

Comment: @Steve, I am defining data[] above the `function getdata()` as a global..